# Kohana 3.2 route not matching

Tags: php, regex, kohana

this is the route that makes problems:

```
Route::set('api', 'api(/<action>(/<currency_data>(/<currency_value>)))',
    array(
        'currency_data' => '(\d\-\d)|(\w\-\w)',
        'currency_value' => '\d+(\.\d{1,2})?'
    ))
    ->defaults(array(
        'controller' => 'api',
        'action'     => 'get',
    ));
```

the url would be something like:

```
/api/currency/123-321/123.00
```

or

```
/api/currency/abc-cba/123
```

both scenarios are covered but at the end do not work, why?
the default rout is at the end of bootstrap(i know someone will suggest that)

tnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\d and \w only match one character. Therefore 123-321 does not match \d-\d and abc-cba does not match \w-\w.

If this is not the problem then please give more information on how it "does not work". What does work? What is the result you get, etc.

Comment: tnx dude

it passes now the 1st regex(i added {1,4} after both \d and \w and it worked like a charm

but...yeah there is a but:<br>
i cannot use floats for the last argument...it does not pass, but a integer works just fine? obviously i missed something

Answer (score 0):

Im an idiot and sry if any of you tried to solve my problem...

i commented the second regex and that the obvious reason why it did not work...tnx everyone